# The Command Prompt just hangs after executing my java program

Tags: java

It seems like there is no problem with this code (here it is):

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumberGuessingGame {

    static int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 11);

    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    static int guessedNumber = userInput.nextInt();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        start: {

            while (guessedNumber != randomNumber) {

                System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number in my mind between 0 and 10. ");

                delay(1500);

                System.out.print("Try to guess it: ");

                if (guessedNumber == randomNumber) {

                    System.out.print("Congradulations! ");

                    delay(800);

                    System.out.println("The number really was " + randomNumber);

                } else {

                    break start;

                }
            }
        }


    }

    public static void delay(int millis) {

       try {

               Thread.sleep(millis);

           } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
       }

    }   
}
```

If you couldn't tell already I'm a beginner trying to create a basic number guessing game. So I successfully coded it but now every time I execute it this happens:

[image: prompt]

It just freezes. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your program is waiting for an user input. According to the docs, a [Scanning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) operation may block waiting for input

The solution is implementing a do/while and userInput and guessedNumber initialized when they are required.

### NumberGuessingGame:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumberGuessingGame {

static int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 11);

static Scanner userInput;

static int guessedNumber;


public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number in my mind between 0 and 10. ");

        do
        {

            
            delay(1500);

            System.out.print("Try to guess it: ");
            userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            guessedNumber = userInput.nextInt();

            if (guessedNumber == randomNumber) {

                System.out.print("Congratulations! ");

                delay(800);

                System.out.println("The number really was " + randomNumber);

            } else {

                System.out.println("Error, try again! ");

                delay(800);

            }
        }
        while (guessedNumber != randomNumber);

}

public static void delay(int millis) {

   try {

           Thread.sleep(millis);

       } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
   }

}   

}
```

Documentation:

[do-while statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: Thanks alot, i really appreciate your time and effort especially with someone as boneheaded as me, i really didnt think id get an answer in the same hour i posted the question.

Comment: One more thing, it said the class, interface or enum expected for the public static void delay, what does his mean?

Comment: It looks like a block error, check your opening and closing brackets. Your methods (main and delay) should be inside NumberGuessingGame class brackets.

Comment: ok now its saying something about cannot find symbol for the while (guessedNumber != randomnumber)

Comment: check out the scope of those variables. Anyway they are correct in the answer.

Comment: @ZaidA Can you try to change `static int guessedNumber;` to `static int guessedNumber = -1;` please?

Comment: it completely worked like 18 hours ago and i forgot to tell you anything, but i am still a beginner, and when i reach a high enough reputation to chat with u i willl because i run into so many problems with my code and u seem like u could help me

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're putting the `userInput.nextInt()` call in the initializer for a static field; so it gets called (and the program pauses for input) as your class is loading, before it can pribt a prompt requesting the input. So it looks like it froze, but if you enter a number it will then proceed.

You want the `nextInt()` call to be inside your method after the calls that prompt for input

Comment: can u tell exactly where to put everything so i can fix it

Comment: Looks like Thrasher's answer has that covered

Answer (score -1):

its probably waiting for you to enter a number. I conformed its not hanging.  its waiting for user input. try entering a number.

Comment: and what happens after the user enters the wrong number?

Comment: @ScaryWombat It just ends. (else -> break)

Comment: If this is not reproducible or based on something unintended, then please just flag to close as such. These posts are not useful for anyone else.

Comment: @ScaryWombat but that was not the question. he was confused as in if the command prompt is freezing. which is no the case and if users enters something it does work weather correct or not thats separate question. I am sure he will debug it more and make it correct.